# Prove a non-decreasing sequence diverges to infinity

Tags: limits, cauchy-sequences

**Question:**

($a_n$) and ($b_n$) are non-decreasing function with the property that for each postiive integer $n$, there are integers $q$ and $p$ such that 
($a_n$) $\leq$ ($b_p$) and  ($b_n$) $\leq$ ($a_q$).

Show that both diverge to infinity.

**IDEA:**
I have some ideas but I don't know how to do the following steps or I don't know how to expand my ideas into a proof.

Since ($a_n$) is a non-decreasing sequence, then it is bounded below.
Suppose ($a_n$) is also bounded above, then ($a_n$) is bounded.

If ($a_n$) is bounded, then there exist a number $M$ such that $|a_n| \le M$, then I am thinking that maybe I can use proof by contradiction to show that 
$|a_n| \ge M$ and prove that ($a_n$) diverges to infinity.

Idea 2:

Proof ($a_n$) is not Cauchy, I am thinking applying the definition of Cauchy sequence and do the following steps. But, I don't where to start or what relationship I can use to start my proof.

Thanks a lot! Any help will be very appreciated.

-JY

Comment: You must have this wrong. Consider, for instance, $a_n=b_n=0$ for all $n$. The sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ satisfy your conditions, but both are convergent.

Comment: So if a sequence is non-decreasing and bounded below, it cannot be divergent?

Comment: No, that's completely wrong. (For starters, _every_ non-decreasing sequence is bounded below!)

Comment: If you mean non-decreasing and bounded above, I think you just mean the [Bolzano-Weierstrauss theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Should I delete this post? Just in case it won't confuse other people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is false even if we change $\le$ into $<$ in the given condition.

Consider
$$
a_n=1-\frac{1}{2n},\qquad b_n=1-\frac{1}{2n+1}
$$
Both sequences are increasing and, for each $n$,
$$
a_n<b_n<a_{n+1}
$$
so we can take $p=n$ and $q=n+1$. However, both sequences converge to $1$.

What is true is that two sequences with that property are either both divergent or both convergent (to the same limit).

Let's see why. Suppose $(a_n)$ is convergent to $l$; then
$$
l=\sup\{a_n:n\ge1\}
$$
Let $n$ be any positive integer; then $b_n\le a_q$, for some $q$; therefore $b_n\le l$ and so the sequence $(b_n)$ is bounded by $l$. As a consequence it converges to $m=\sup\{b_n:n\ge1\}$ and $m\le l$.

Now, for every $n$, $a_n\le b_p$, for some $p$; therefore $a_n\le m$. As before, $l\le m$.

Hence $l=m$.

By symmetry, if one of the two sequences diverges, also the other one does.

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean by either both divergent or both convergent? Only be divergent or only be convergent to the same limit?

Comment: @JoyYin If one is divergent, then also the other is; if one is convergent to $l$, then also the other one converges to $l$.